# How can I hide the top blue bar in SP 2013?

Tags: 2013, ribbon

What code can I use to hide the top blue bar in SP 2013? I know the steps and have done it for SP2010, but need to do the same on SP2013.

Thanks!

Comment: There are ways to remove/changes links but I don't see the purpose of hiding the top suite bar?

Answer (score 3):

You can use css or javascript to hide the top blue bar:
using this style in your css file:

```
#suiteBar
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Or using this command in your document ready function:

```
$('#suiteBar').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

suiteBarTop is the ID of the top blue bar in SP 2013.

```
#suiteBarTop
{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it via CSS if you don't have access to your master page:

```
#suiteBar, #s4-ribbonrow
{
    display: none;
}
```

If you can access the master page, look for "ribbon" in it and remove it, to prevent the server from rendering it for the client; for instance, remove the following:

```
<!-- Start Ribbon -->
<PublishingRibbon:PublishingRibbon runat="server"/>
<!-- End Ribbon -->
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#ms-designer-ribbon
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: ms- designer-ribbon is name of css ID. Use symbol '#' before ms-designer-ribbon.